# XML Schema Case Insensitive Enumeration of Simple Type String

Tags: xml, schema, simpletype, case-sensitive

I am in need of a case insensitive string enumeration type in my XML schema (.xsd) file. I can get case insensitive by doing the following.

```
<xs:simpleType name="setDigitalPointType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[Oo][Nn]" />
        <xs:pattern value="[Oo][Ff][Ff]" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The only problem is that I get no enumeration values. I will not get the nice intellesense  when using Visual Studio to write my XML. The following will give me enumerations but it is case sensitive.

```
<xs:simpleType name="setDigitalPointType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="on" />
        <xs:enumeration value="off" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This will give me my enumerations but if I ever receive a value of "On", "ON", or "oN" it will fail verification.

I want enumeration of "on", "off" and allow entry of case insensitive versions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IBM developerWorks has [an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20091206195708/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-case/) on how to use XSLT to perform the construction of the full set of enumeration alternatives in an automated fashion. It is presented as a workaround to the lack of case-insensitive enumerations.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to both keep the case-insensitive validation, while still getting Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010, you can use a union:

```
<xs:simpleType name="setDigitalPointType">
    <xs:union>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="on" />
                <xs:enumeration value="off" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[Oo][Nn]" />
                <xs:pattern value="[Oo][Ff][Ff]" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This works because it exploits the fact that Visual Studio 2010 only processes the first simple type in a union when it builds it's Intellisense data. However when it validates a document, it processes both, which means "On" is still determined to be valid even though it isn't in the list of enumeration values.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just list all the permutations as patterns :)

Comment: I could but this isn't elegant for long enumeration values like "notification" and I still don't get my enumeration. The enumeration is very important for me. :)