# XML element and attribute names

Tags: xml

Can `XML`, `xml`, `xML` or any variation of upper and lowercase versions of **"xml"** be used as element or attribute names in `xml`?

If not why not?

**Edit1**

I am referring to naming elements or attributes. Not doctype

**Edit2**

I am not suggesting this would be a good name for an element or attribute, I could not find a definitive answer for this.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414747/is-xml-case-sensitive

Comment: I'd say yes - you can use any word you want, but I wouldn't recommend using xml as attribute or element name

Comment: @Skippy Good question Skippy. Personally I would say "Hey, if they're letters and they all spell out `X-M-L` and that doesn't stand for "X-Large, Medium, Large", then I say why not? You can always implement an `strtolower` or `strtoupper` function if needed to convert the `xMl` string to upper or lowercase. We have the power ;)

Comment: @Skippy You could say... used to be in a trade where clothing was part of the line... "clothes line" that is ;)

Comment: @Skippy Yeah but the smell of clothes on a clothes line in Spring, cannot be beat! Aahhh Ireland, where art though now?

Comment: @Skippy Not though......... but "thy"? Mine Olde English is a bit roosty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While most tools probably don't prevent it, it's probably a bad practice. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name

> Names beginning with the string "xml", or with any string which would match (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')), are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.

ie, it might work now...

Answer (score 5):

Although it's not prohibited, take a look at the [Suggestions for XML Names (Non-Normative)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-suggested-names):

> Names which are nonsensical, unpronounceable, hard to read, or **easily
>   confusable with other names should not be employed**.

Answer (score 4):

XML format's definition does not prohibit it: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name

You can check it here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp - even "xml" tags validate without errors.