# Error in JAXB unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have created a very basic XML for understanding JAXB Concept. This is the XML File

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>

    <Abc>

        <Module> India </Module>

     </Abc>
```

The Java Class created is,

```
package oracle.ERP.Cloud.Client2;

import java.util.ArrayList;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

//Below annotation defines root element of XML file
@XmlRootElement
public class Abc{

 private String Module;

 public String getModule() {
   System.out.println("Hi");
  return Module;
 }

 @XmlElement
 public void setModule(String Module) {
  this.Module = Module;
 }

}
```

Java file for Unmarshalling is

```
package oracle.ERP.Cloud.client2;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import oracle.ERP.Cloud.Client2.Abc;
import oracle.ERP.Cloud.client.Country;

public class JAXBXMLToJava {

    public static void main(String Args[]) {
      try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{oracle.ERP.Cloud.Client2.Abc.class});
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        File XMLFile = new File("C:\\Users\\NRENTALA\\Desktop\\Analysis\\AbcXML.xml");
        oracle.ERP.Cloud.Client2.Abc summary = oracle.ERP.Cloud.Client2.Abc)unmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLFile);
        System.out.println("Country Name is : "+ summary.getModule());
      }

      catch(JAXBException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this I am getting this error

```
    javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Abc"). Expected elements are <{}abc>
```

Please help me in finding out what is the problem?? Trying this for the first time.

Comment: Why is your code in a oracle's package? How did you generate your class?

Comment: Could you post oracle.ERP.Cloud.Client2.Abc summary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is case sensitive, so if your schema specifies the root element to be called "abc" (as the error message suggests), it will not be able to parse "Abc". Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414747/is-xml-case-sensitive).

To achieve case insensitive parsing, have a look at [this blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/case-insensitive-unmarshalling.html) by Blaise Doughan, one of the people behind specification and implementation of JAXB.

Comment: Thankyou very much. It has solved the problem. But What if the XML elements contains all upper case letters? How do we parse such an XML. 
I actually need to parse an XML which has all uppercase letters.