# python findall() returns empty list

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, openapi

I want to use Python to get open API data. So, I parsed the URL to XML and tried to get the information I wanted through findall().

part of the data,

```
<safemap:CTPRVN_CD>11</safemap:CTPRVN_CD>
<safemap:SGG_CD>11500</safemap:SGG_CD>
```

i want this,

```
root.findall('safemap:ctprvn_cd')
```

but returned empty list.

Comment: casing matters IIRC

Comment: Isn't findall() case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

XML is [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414747/is-xml-case-sensitive). I believe that `root.findall('safemap:CTPRVN_CD')` might work better.

Also I noticed that your xml seems to use [namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp). Usually there is a problem with namespaces, when working with xmls using `lxml` or `xml` package in python.

Comment: Start with getting rid of namespaces in your xml and using `findall` only wth  `CTPRVN_CD` . If that helps read something about [working with namespaces in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053568/how-do-i-use-empty-namespaces-in-an-lxml-xpath-query)