# XBRL Qname question: is qname case-sensitive

Tags: taxonomy, xbrl

Is Qname (name) of the element is case-sensitive? For example, there are 2 versions of one element in the dictionary: Deposit and DEPOSIT.

I would like to know the answer.
But I think that there is no difference. So if anybody knows, please  help me

Comment: Out of curiosity: do these two concepts belong to the same namespace? deposit and DEPOSIT are local names, i.e., the right-hand-sides of QNames.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, QNames in XBRL are case sensitive.  This is inherited from the behaviour of XML, in which names are case sensitive.  See [Is XML case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414747/is-xml-case-sensitive)

Comment: Indeed it is. But it is not recommended design to have two XBRL concepts with QNames only differing by case because that can lead to confusion. The common practice for open taxonomy architectures (EDGAR, ESEF...) is to use CamelCase for QNames. And closed taxonomy architectures (DPM) typically use standard codes, not English words.